# Assigning a hover then blur to an object with a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a load of projects, I also have a mouseover effect which puts a layer with text over the top when you hover over it.
I have realised that now some text is not legible and need to add a blur when you hover over each project

For example, when I hover over project 1, the text shows up and the project 1 image blurs.

[I have set up a JSFiddle here too](http://jsfiddle.net/zdLpkgc6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="projectswrap">
    <div class="project project1">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover1">Hover text #1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project project2">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover2">Hover text #2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project project3">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover3">Hover text #3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project project4">
        <div class="project-hover project-hover4">Hover text #4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.projectswrap {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.projectswrap .project {
    width:48%;
    padding-bottom:48%;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    background:rgb(204,234,236);
    position: relative;
}
.projectswrap .project .project-hover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    background: coral;
}
.projectswrap .project:hover .project-hover {
    display: block;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is wrap image inside another div.
Then, upon hovering .project div, add blur to it's child image wrapper.

I updated your fiddle to show what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/zdLpkgc6/3/

HTML

```
 <div class="project project1">
        <div class="image"><img src="your/image.jpg"></div>
        <div class="project-hover project-hover1">Hover text #1</div>
 </div>
```

And CSS

```
  .project {overflow: hidden;}

  .projectswrap .project:hover .image {
      -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
      -moz-filter: blur(5px);
      -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
      filter: blur(5px);
    }
```

And you can even make it lot more beautiful by adding smooth transition for blur using CSS. Example http://jsfiddle.net/zdLpkgc6/3/

```
.image {
   position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;                  
   -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;                 
   -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;   
   -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease;          
   transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
```